# Django settings Unknown parameters: TEMPLATE_DEBUG

Tags: python, django, django-1.9

Hi I'm following the tutorial on the [djangoproject site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.9/intro/tutorial03/) and I'm getting an error on my localhost saying:

```
Unknown parameters: TEMPLATE_DEBUG
```

My settings.py looks like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'TEMPLATE_DEBUG':True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I added the 'TEMPLATE_DEBUG' on TEMPLATE because otherwise I'm getting the following warning

```
?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DEBUG.
```

My templates folder are in my apps i.e.:

```
my_project_name/polls/templates/polls/index.html
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you need to do:

```
DEBUG = True 

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # something else
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
        },
    },
]
```

*Django used to accept TEMPLATE_DEBUG variable but since **Django >= 1.8**, this not allowed any more and is replaced as explained above.*

Django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/upgrading/).

Comment: Ok I get it now `If it sets TEMPLATE_DEBUG to a value that differs from DEBUG, include that value under the 'debug' key in 'OPTIONS'.` Thanks!